# Template Class and Auxiliary Streaming In/Out Functions

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to create a template class in C++ and i originally had code that worked with a header file and a CPP file however now that im trying to move my functions from the CPP file to the header file i'm getting some errors. I have two auxiliary functions to stream in and out to the console and the class parameter in the function is showing an error.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& sout, Grid& grid)
{
    grid.SaveGrid(sout);
}


void operator>>(istream& sin, Grid &grid)
{
    grid.LoadGrid(sin);
}
```

This is how they originally looked and worked before changing my class to a template class.

The part of the parameters above that doesn't work is this.
"Grid &grid"

FULL CODE

```
#pragma once

#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Grid
{
public:
    //Grid();
    //~Grid();
    Grid::Grid()
    {
    }
    Grid::~Grid()
    {
    }

    //void LoadGrid(const char filename[]);
    //void LoadGrid(istream& sin);
    void Grid<T>::LoadGrid(const char filename[])
    {
        ifstream file(filename);
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                file >> m_grid[x][y];
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
    void Grid<T>::LoadGrid(istream& sin)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                sin >> m_grid[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
    //void SaveGrid(const char filename[]);
    //void SaveGrid(ostream& sout);
    void Grid<T>::SaveGrid(const char filename[])
    {
        ofstream file(filename);
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                file << m_grid[x][y] << " ";
            }
            file << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }

    void Grid<T>::SaveGrid(ostream & sout)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                sout << m_grid[x][y] << " ";
            }
            sout << endl;
        }
    }
private:
    T m_grid[9][9];
};


ostream& operator<<(ostream& sout, Grid<T>& grid)
{
    grid.SaveGrid(sout);
}


void operator>>(istream& sin, Grid<T>& grid)
{
    grid.LoadGrid(sin);
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You've got a missing comma in `ostream& operator<<(ostream& sout Grid& grid)`

Comment: @nick sorry that was meant to be there doesn't work with it still.

Comment: Shouldn't they also be templates? I.e. `Grid<T>& grid`

Comment: @nick yeah that works but then it just says T is undefined.

Comment: @OwenHodgson Did you add `template<typename T>` before each function?

Comment: Sorry, I figured it was enough to imply that `template <typename T>` would precede each function.

Comment: Note: No need for the `Grid::` in  `Grid::Grid()` when implementing a method inside the class definition. Another note: if a constructor or destructor does nothing, leave them out and let the compiler auto generate.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've just done that now but still the same error on my auxiliary functions i'll edit post to show my full code as it looks now with the changes.

Comment: @OwenHodgson Also include the exact error text

Comment: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& sout, Grid<T>& grid)` must have a return statement or the function invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). `void operator>>(istream& sin, Grid<T>& grid)` should return an `istream` to be a correct streaming operator.

Comment: @user4581301 was just about to add that but thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ostream& operator<<(ostream& sout, Grid& grid)
> ```

does not work because `Grid` is a class template, not a class. You need to use:

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& sout, Grid<T>& grid)
{
    grid.SaveGrid(sout);
}
```

To make it `const` correct, use

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& sout, Grid<T> const& grid)
{
    grid.SaveGrid(sout);
}
```

Note that, you'll need to make `SaveGrid` a `const` member function for the above change to work.

```
void Grid::SaveGrid(const char filename[]) const
{
   ...
}

void Grid::SaveGrid(ostream& sout) const
{
   ...
}
```

Make similar changes to the other function.

Comment: Thanks this works. For the member methods can i do this.  void Grid<T>::SaveGrid(ostream & sout)

Comment: @OwenHodgson, I didn't notice that you have two `SaveGrid` functions. I updated the answer.